# Word for scold in America

Tags: verbs, american-english, transatlantic-differences

What do Americans usually use instead of word scold ? For example parents scold their children when they act up . How would write same sentence but with American version of scold?

Comment: What about **tell off**?

Comment: I don't think "scold" is particularly rare in American English.

Comment: Normally, "scold" is used.

Comment: The [Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=scold%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cscold%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cscold%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cscold%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0) also doesn't show any particular trans-atlantic difference in the usage of "scold".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question until it's edited to give a better explanation of why the word "scold" doesn't suffice.

Comment: Some of the answers on [this similar question on the ELL site](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/109285/how-would-you-say-to-scold-in-a-less-formal-way/109330) might help.

Answer (score 0):

#### Scold

If you look at [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=scold%3Aeng_us_2009%2Cscold%3Aeng_gb_2009&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cscold%3Aeng_us_2009%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cscold%3Aeng_gb_2009%3B%2Cc0) and compare the two uses, **scold** is actually used *more* in American English than in British English.

[image: Ngrams]